# Remove last character from column's value if its comma

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to remove last character from column's value only if the last char is comma *,*

This will always remove last char:

```
select left(columnx,-1) from myTable;
```

**Example input:**

```
10,23,
11
```

**Output should be:**

```
10,23
11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [trim](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html):

```
trim(trailing ',' from '10,23,')
```